# load django templatetags from custom location

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to load custom templatetags from **nonstandard location**, ie. not from `project.myapp.templatetags`, but from **`project.myapp.extra_level.templatetags`**.

I can load them globally using `django.template.base.add_to_builtins` but that is just bad practice IMHO.

```
from django.template.base import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('myapp.extra_level.templatetags.custom_tags')
```

Since a setting similar to "TEMPLATE_DIRS" unfortunately does not exist I had to get creative. An option like that would be a life saver :)

First idea was to use something similar to `load_all_installed_template_libraries` from `django.contrib.admindocs.views` and load it in my settings, but of course I get "RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet.".

Another idea was to load those deeper templatetags in `project.myapp.__init__` (for all those templatetag libraries which are in `project.myapp.extra_level.templatetags`) but loading of templatetag libraries is based on files.

Any way to achieve this? Perhaps I could somehow fake deeper files and fake show them through `__init__` file? Or is there a better way to load templatetags from custom location?

Comment: Can't you just add `project.myapp.extra_level` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings?

Comment: @LudwikTrammer that would be the obvious solution, but I can't do that in my case because I would get conflicting apps (since the apps with the same names already exist in one of the installed packages)